# Firebase doesn't return value (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, firebase, angular

I try to retrieve data from my Firebase and it works, but JUST for console.log().
I can't return a value into a var...

As I'm working with Angular 2 & Typescript I have

a Service:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
declare var Firebase: any;

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

    getAllData() {

        const firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://XYZ.firebaseio.com/path/user')
        firebaseRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot.val()); // THIS WORKS!
            return snapshot.val(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK!
        });
    }
```

and a Component:

```
@Component({
templateUrl: 'templates/user.tpl.html',
providers: [DataService],
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit{
userData: any;

constructor(private _dataService: DataService){}

ngOnInit():any {
    this.userData = this._dataService.getAllData(); 
    console.log(this.userData); // THIS DOES NOT WORK: UNDEFINED
}
```

If i run that, I get nothing for my userData var... And I can't figure how to fix that. I thought I would need an Observable but I failed, whatever I tried to do...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your call into an observable since Firebase is event-driven:

```
getAllData() {
  const firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://XYZ.firebaseio.com/path/user')
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    firebaseRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        observer.next(snapshot.val());

    });
  });
}
```

This way you will be able to receive value by subscribing on the returned observable:

```
ngOnInit():any {
  this._dataService.getAllData().subscribe(data => {
    this.userData = data;
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It now works but somehow, the values won't display in my input fields (as default values) of my formbuilder:

https://codeshare.io/XSAzO

Comment: I added a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031910/angular-2-formbuilder-with-observables-as-default-values

Comment: In fact the data is loaded asynchronously. So it's not there when the form is created. I would update the input later (within the subscribe callback) like this: `this.userForm.controls.username.updateValue(this.userData.username);`